# Problemas en Python

Tags: python-2.7

Hola que tal? Estaba usando Python hace unos dias y no tenia problema, ayer que quise modificar mi codigo me salio un problema a la hora de compilar: 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 30: ordinal not in range(128)

Por lo que he leido dicen que es problema de acentos o eñes, en mi programa no hay nada de eso, ahora lo copio para que lo vean, necesito de su ayuda... estoy desesperada

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Created on Wed Dec 13 17:41:56 2017

@author: pc
"""



# when ddepth=-1, the output image will have the same depth as the source
# cv2.CV_64F

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.patches as patches

import numpy as np
import cv2

from Class_2D_DoG import DoG_2D
from func_Custom import (Convert255ToBalanced, ConvertBalancedTo255)

import os
import sys
import scipy.io


#Ploting Settings
m=0.5
graph_size = (m*19.2, m*10.8)
graph_dpi = 300

if __name__ == "__main__":

#==============================================================================
#   Setting the DoG Filter
#==============================================================================

    #Set DoG Filter Parameters
    Rc = 1.5
    rR = 2.5
    rV = 0.95


    #Create Class: DoG Filter
    DoG = DoG_2D(Rc=Rc, rR=rR, rV=rV)

#==============================================================================
#   Setting First Derivative Filter    
#==============================================================================
    #First Derivate Filter: Horizontal and Veritical Directions
    dx1 = np.array([[0,0,0],[-1.0,0,1.0],[0,0,0]])
    dy1 = np.array([[0,0,0],[-1.0,0,1.0],[0,0,0]]).T

#==============================================================================
#   Setting the Folder
#==============================================================================
    #Set the folder
    main_path = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]) 
    pupil_name = 'p3'
    img_name = 'Flores'    

    #Get file names from AD-
    data_path_neg = os.path.join(main_path, pupil_name, img_name,'AD-')
    AD_neg  = os.listdir(data_path_neg)
    AD_neg  = AD_neg[0:13]
    AD_neg  = AD_neg[::-1]

    #Get file names from AD+
    data_path_pos = os.path.join(main_path, pupil_name, img_name, 'AD+')
    AD_pos  = os.listdir(data_path_pos)
    AD_pos  = AD_pos[0:13]

#==============================================================================
#   Processing Loop 
#==============================================================================
    n = 25
    AD = np.linspace(-3.0,+3.0, n)  
    Focus_DoG = np.zeros(n)
    Focus_D1 = np.zeros(n)

    for i in range(0,n):
        if i < 12:
            mat = scipy.io.loadmat(data_path_neg + '//' + AD_neg[i])  
            imgIn = mat['imag']
        else:
            mat = scipy.io.loadmat(data_path_pos + '//' + AD_pos[i-12])  
            imgIn = mat['imag']



        #Convert input image from [0...128...255] to [-1...0...+1] (Optional)
#        imgIn = Convert255ToBalanced(imgIn)
#        imgIn = ConvertBalancedTo255(imgIn)

        #Calculating: DoG Output
        imgOut = cv2.filter2D(imgIn, cv2.CV_64F, DoG.Filter)

        #Calculating: Focus Metric Based on DoG
        [r,c] = imgIn.shape
        Focus_DoG[i] = np.sum(np.sqrt(imgOut**2))/float(r*c)


        #Calculating: First Derivative
        Out_dx1 = cv2.filter2D(imgIn, cv2.CV_64F, dx1)
        Out_dy1 = cv2.filter2D(imgIn, cv2.CV_64F, dy1)

        #Calculating: Focus Metric Based on First Derivative
        Focus_D1[i] = np.sum(np.sqrt(Out_dx1**2 + Out_dy1**2))/float(r*c)



#==============================================================================
#   Correcting the Shift (Optional but recommended for "p3" data)
#==============================================================================

#    if pupil_name == 'p3':
#        AD = AD - 0.25
#        AD = AD[2:]
#        Focus_DoG = Focus_DoG[2:]
#        Focus_D1 = Focus_D1[2:]

#==============================================================================
#   Normalizing the Focus Metrics to the Maximum Value to make comparision.
#==============================================================================

    Focus_DoG_norm = Focus_DoG/Focus_DoG.max()
    Focus_D1_norm = Focus_D1/Focus_D1.max()

#==============================================================================
#   Plotting    
#==============================================================================

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)  
    fig.set_size_inches(graph_size)  

    ax[0].plot(AD, Focus_D1_norm,'-or', label='1D')
    ax[0].vlines(x=0, ymin=ax[0].axes.get_ylim()[0], ymax=ax[0].axes.get_ylim()[1], linestyle='--', color='k')  
    ax[0].hlines(y=1, xmin=ax[0].axes.get_xlim()[0], xmax=ax[0].axes.get_xlim()[1], linestyle='--', color='k')
    ax[0].legend()

    ax[1].plot(AD, Focus_DoG_norm,'-og', label='DoG')
    ax[1].vlines(x=0, ymin=ax[1].axes.get_ylim()[0], ymax=ax[1].axes.get_ylim()[1], linestyle='--', color='k')  
    ax[1].hlines(y=1, xmin=ax[1].axes.get_xlim()[0], xmax=ax[1].axes.get_xlim()[1], linestyle='--', color='k')    
    ax[1].legend()

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Hola Azucena, bienvenida a [es.so]. Deberías colocar la **traza completa del error** para ver si podemos ver de dónde viene exactamente. Es posible que el problema esté en en los módulos `Class_2D_DoG` o `func_Custom` . Recuerda que si especificas el encoding como UTF-8 (`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`) debes guardar el script con esa codificación. Un saludo.

Comment: Lo extraño es que ya había podido generar gráficas y compilar el problema, pero últimamente me marca esos errores, no se si sea problema de alguna librería o algo así.

Comment: Azucena como te comenté arriba es importante que coloques la traza completa del error (todas las líneas del error y no solo la última línea) porque nos va a orientar bastante por donde mirar (linea, método, módulo, etc donde se produce el error). vigila que no abrieras el archivo con otro editor o que por descuido cambiaras la codificación con el que guardaste el módulo.

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error de python te dice que encontró un carácter no válido y te muestra su código hexadecimal: `0xf3`.

Ese código corresponde a la vocal o acentuada `ó` usando un *encoding* ISO-8859-1. Por tanto, algunas cosas raras:

1. La primera línea de tu código declara codificación `utf-8`. En cambio el carácter por el que se queja corresponde a una codificación ISO.
2. Más raro aún, el código que has pegado es ASCII puro, no contiene caracteres en otras codificaciones (ni utf ni ISO). En ese sentido sobraría la primera línea que declara el encoding.

¿De dónde ha salido por tanto la letra `ó` que está causando problemas? Lo más probable es que esté dentro de alguno de los ficheros que estás leyendo. Para localizar mejor el fallo deberías indicar en qué línea te salta la excepción. Por cierto que el error estaría ocurriendo *al ejecutar el programa* y no al compilarlo. Seguramente está ocurriendo al crear la etiqueta para alguno de los gráficos. Es difícil ayudarte a arrelgarlo sin más detalles.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, sigo sin poder solucionar el problema del código, si me dices que mas puedo adjuntar yo podría enviarte o subir otros códigos para generar mis gráficas.